# Is it appropriate to extend JPanel to create a drawing surface for a 2D game?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm converting a 2D game from an Applet to a JFrame. I know I should add a JPanel to a JFrame and use the JPanel as my drawing surface but I'm not sure exactly what I should be subclassing. I was trying it with JFrame but I've read that it's usually unnecessary and a bad idea to extend JFrame (I wasn't adding any extra functionality anyway, so that makes sense). I need to override the `paintComponent()` method of JPanel so right now I'm leaning towards extending JPanel. Is there a better way of creating a 2D game surface or is extending JPanel and adding that to a JFrame an appropriate way to do it?

Comment: You are correct -- go with JPanel or JComponent and override paintComponent. Look at doing your background drawing into a BufferedImage which you will draw in the paintComponent method immediately after calling the super method. Sprites will likely be drawn directly in the paintComponent method above the BufferedImage.   Also 1+ to @Snicolas for his good recs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no better way, that's a very good option.
If you would extend a JFrame (the other option), your animation would blink on most windows family OS.

JPanel is a pure swing component and reacts better in java than a peered component like a JFrame.

Your choice is good, go ahead and have fun programming.

Comment: oh, and if it's for a game, don't forget to override the isFocusable method, and make it return true, so that you can catch key presses.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Not only will this work better but it also fixed the annoying problem I was having before where my JPanel would draw underneath the title bar.

Comment: Back at Java-gaming.org we had a member that was adamant that JComponent was more correct than JPanel. His reasoning, if I remember correctly, was that JPanel (a subclass of JComponent) adds unused functionality, e.g., the ability to add yet more Java components, which are often not needed for games. I don't think it really matters all that much which one you use (between JComponent and JPanel).

Answer (score 0):

**update**

My knowledge in this area has grown since I originally answered the question and I agree with @Snicolas that you should use a JPanel.

JPanel (because it's a swing component) has builtin support for double buffering (AWT does not) and has better performance (so I hear, but I have no first hand experience with this).

You may find this article useful: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#swing

**original answer:**

I recommend you subclass [Canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html) or Component or JComponent.  My preference is Canvas.  You should read the [2d graphics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html).

**update**

Use Canvas because it receives all the user input events and doesn't have the baggage of being a container.  [read more](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/canvas.html).  Panels don't receive all mouse input events, for instance.

Comment: Please give reasons for your preference for Canvas. Why use that over JComponent or JPanel? Why ask the OP to create their own back buffer for double buffering rather than let Swing components do this for you automatically?